# Using bind(this) together with jQuery.each, ambiguous use of "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I've got a complex JS app, OOP style, where objects hirearchy is used. Class Grandfather is extended by class Father, which is extended by class Child. I've got different instances of class Child.

To avoid property confusion and mix-up, I am heavily using .bind(this) to callback. Example

```
$(this.buttonId).click(function(evt)) {
    console.log(this.myProperty);
    this.myMethod();
}.bind(this));
```

In this way I am sure that this.myProperty and this.myMethod are always "mine", and not my father's or my brother's.

Now i need to rely on [jQuery.each method](https://api.jquery.com/each/). But to access each item I need "this" again!

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

So, if I bind the callback to "this" (object), it's going to become:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
    console.log(this.myProperty);
    this.myMethod();
}.bind(this));
```

causing an ambiguous use of "this" which, of course, leads to lots of errors.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: How do you get access to first `this`, the one whose class implementation you have defined?

Comment: I suppose that `$(this).text()` you want to be called over the target DOM node and `this.myMethod()` to be called over the instance of your class. If so than using `bind` will not help you, you have to use two different variables, in other words, let `this` to be the reference to the DOM node, and have another variable for the instance of your class.

Comment: You can use `$(selector).each` like this: `$( "li" ).each( function( index, element) {
  conslole.log(index + ": " + $(element).text()
});`

Comment: Make a [mcve] that shows your object hierarchy and reproduces the errors you see. You can put runnable JS right into your question here, click the "snippet" button in the editor. The description alone is much vague to actually help you.

Comment: $( "li" ).each( function( index, element) of "fen1x" actually solved!

Answer (score 0):

Set a local variable before jquery-each function:

```
var me = this;
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
console.log(me.myProperty);
});
```